# How to hide sensitive API keys from index.android.bundle in React Native Applications

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I can see my **API** keys in the **`index.android.bundle`** file of the react native application after decompiling it.

I tried to use `react-native-dotenv`, but still there is the *string* of api key in `index.android.bundle` file.

The API key is sensitive, but anyone can see that key by decompiling the app.

Is there any way to hide that key?

Comment: Store the API key on the server, and authenticate it with some other non-sensitive values like user_id or JWT.